Error loading Google Cloud Messaging API on Firebase Console
[I have tried retrying the action multiple times and have confirmed that I have the necessary permissions set to 'Editor,' but unfortunately, none of these attempts have resolved the issue.] I am trying to generate server key for notification on firebase console, but as I click on "Manage API on Google Console" from the right option, then it leads to google cloud page with an error message.
There was an error while loading /apis/library/googlecloudmessaging.googleapis.com?authuser=0&project=chatapplication-299cd&hl=en. Please try again.
It may be a browser or network issue. Go to the loading issues help page  to troubleshoot the issue.
Request ID: 5475914060479467577
It may be a browser or network issue. Go to the loading issues help page to troubleshoot the issue.
I expected to be able to access the API settings for Google Cloud Messaging without encountering any errors.
Specifically, I wanted to generate a server key for Firebase Notifications.

If you're referring to the Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) Server Key, it's already deprecated last 6/20/2023 and will shutdown beginning on July 22, 2024.
Moving forward, you must use or migrate to FCM HTTP v1 API or consider using the Admin SDK to build and send requests. You may also check this FCM FAQ for more information about this.
